How to show Admob's app open ad on system splash screen in Android device(Flutter)
I am running my app on android 12 and In that I can see two splash First one when app open It shows appicon on it and second my app's splash screen that I have craeted in dart
So now I have removed my created splash screen in dart
But there is one app open ad feature that I want on system splash open,
Whats should I do.
condition is, it doesn't open on next screen,It only have to visible on system default splash screen
Please let me know If you have any solution for that.
Thanks

So you want Your splash screen or system splash screen?

I only want system splash and want to show splash on it.
